# Part of dateRangeInput ui gets hidden under the shiny dashboard header

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

Is there a way to always make the ui of `dateRangeInput` fully visible?
 Minimising the window and clicking on the date, this happens:

[image]

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Home", tabName = "Home")
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName = "Home",
        fluidRow(
          br(),
          br(),
          br(),
          br(),
          br(),
          br(),
          box(
            dateRangeInput("daterange", "Date range:", start = "2001-01-01", end = "2010-12-31"),
            title="Select Dates", solidHeader=T, status="primary",width=6,height=250)
        )
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: @SBista Please see above.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use css to make the z-index of .dropdown-menu more than that of dashboard header using the following tag:

`tags$div(tags$style(HTML( ".dropdown-menu{z-index:10000 !important;}")))`

In your apps ui it would be as follows:

```
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Home", tabName = "Home")
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(

    tags$div(tags$style(HTML( ".dropdown-menu{z-index:10000 !important;}"))),

    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName = "Home",
              fluidRow(
                br(),
                br(),
                br(),
                br(),
                br(),
                br(),
                box(
                  dateRangeInput("daterange", "Date range:", start = "2001-01-01", end = "2010-12-31"),
                  title="Select Dates", solidHeader=T, status="primary",width=6,height=250)
              )
      )
    )
  )
)
```

You would get something like this:[image]

Hope it helps!